# How to read the export function names of a (native) DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllexport

I know I can read the [PE specification](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/pecoff.mspx) in order to write a code that does this.
However, since I don't have a lot of time on my hands, I was hoping some of you might already have such a code sample ready to send.

**Important note:** Is there any difference between 32bit and 64bit?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PE File Exports**

The opposite of importing a function is exporting a function for use by EXEs or other DLLs. A PE file stores information about its exported functions in the .edata section. Generally, Microsoft linker-generated PE EXE files don't export anything, so they don't have an .edata section. Borland's TLINK32 always exports at least one symbol from an EXE. Most DLLs do export functions and have an .edata section. The primary components of an .edata section (aka the export table) are tables of function names, entry point addresses, and export ordinal values. In an NE file, the equivalents of an export table are the entry table, the resident names table, and the nonresident names table. These tables are stored as part of the NE header, rather than in distinct segments or resources.

At the start of an .edata section is an IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY structure (see Table 10). This structure is immediately followed by data pointed to by fields in the structure.

Table 10. **IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY** Format

```
DWORD Characteristics
```

This field appears to be unused and is always set to 0.

```
DWORD TimeDateStamp
```

The time/date stamp indicating when this file was created.

```
WORD MajorVersion
WORD MinorVersion
```

These fields appear to be unused and are set to 0.

```
DWORD Name
```

The RVA of an ASCIIZ string with the name of this DLL.

```
DWORD Base
```

The starting ordinal number for exported functions. For example, if the file exports functions with ordinal values of 10, 11, and 12, this field contains 10. To obtain the exported ordinal for a function, you need to add this value to the appropriate element of the AddressOfNameOrdinals array.

```
DWORD NumberOfFunctions
```

The number of elements in the AddressOfFunctions array. This value is also the number of functions exported by this module. Theoretically, this value could be different than the NumberOfNames field (next), but actually they're always the same.

```
DWORD NumberOfNames
```

The number of elements in the AddressOfNames array. This value seems always to be identical to the NumberOfFunctions field, and so is the number of exported functions.

```
PDWORD *AddressOfFunctions
```

This field is an RVA and points to an array of function addresses. The function addresses are the entry points (RVAs) for each exported function in this module.

```
PDWORD *AddressOfNames
```

This field is an RVA and points to an array of string pointers. The strings are the names of the exported functions in this module.

```
PWORD *AddressOfNameOrdinals
```

This field is an RVA and points to an array of WORDs. The WORDs are the export ordinals of all the exported functions in this module. However, don't forget to add in the starting ordinal number specified in the Base field.

The layout of the export table is somewhat odd (see Figure 4 and Table 10). As I mentioned earlier, the requirements for exporting a function are a name, an address, and an export ordinal. You'd think that the designers of the PE format would have put all three of these items into a structure, and then have an array of these structures. Instead, each component of an exported entry is an element in an array. There are three of these arrays (AddressOfFunctions, AddressOfNames, AddressOfNameOrdinals), and they are all parallel to one another. To find all the information about the fourth function, you need to look up the fourth element in each array.

[image]

*Figure 4. Export table layout*

*Table 11. Typical Exports Table from an EXE File*

```
Name:            KERNEL32.dll
  Characteristics: 00000000
  TimeDateStamp:   2C4857D3
  Version:         0.00
  Ordinal base:    00000001
  # of functions:  0000021F
  # of Names:      0000021F

  Entry Pt  Ordn  Name
  00005090     1  AddAtomA
  00005100     2  AddAtomW
  00025540     3  AddConsoleAliasA
  00025500     4  AddConsoleAliasW
  00026AC0     5  AllocConsole
  00001000     6  BackupRead
  00001E90     7  BackupSeek
  00002100     8  BackupWrite
  0002520C     9  BaseAttachCompleteThunk
  00024C50    10  BasepDebugDump
  // Rest of table omitted...
```

Incidentally, if you dump out the exports from the Windows NT system DLLs (for example, KERNEL32.DLL and USER32.DLL), you'll note that in many cases there are two functions that only differ by one character at the end of the name, for instance CreateWindowExA and CreateWindowExW. This is how UNICODE support is implemented transparently. The functions that end with A are the ASCII (or ANSI) compatible functions, while those ending in W are the UNICODE version of the function. In your code, you don't explicitly specify which function to call. Instead, the appropriate function is selected in WINDOWS.H, via preprocessor #ifdefs. This excerpt from the Windows NT WINDOWS.H shows an example of how this works:
Copy

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define DefWindowProc  DefWindowProcW
#else
#define DefWindowProc  DefWindowProcA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

---

```
//
// Export Format
//

typedef struct _IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY {
    DWORD   Characteristics;
    DWORD   TimeDateStamp;
    WORD    MajorVersion;
    WORD    MinorVersion;
    DWORD   Name;
    DWORD   Base;
    DWORD   NumberOfFunctions;
    DWORD   NumberOfNames;
    DWORD   AddressOfFunctions;     // RVA from base of image
    DWORD   AddressOfNames;         // RVA from base of image
    DWORD   AddressOfNameOrdinals;  // RVA from base of image
} IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY, *PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY;
```

---

*EDIT:* In PE format exports table is not diffrent, address of functions is a RVA of 64bit address only.

*Source:* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

Comment: You must read `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` structure from your executable file, i dont have any C# code spinet for it.

Comment: so I need to reach the edata section on my own and then use the struct you gave me?